# Two divs on same position

Tags: html, css

I got two divs. The second div should be on first div, so... When clicking at menu buttons in first div, there should appear second div on first div (the second div covers the first one). I created the second div under first one, gave to it relative position, and took it up to first one. But there is a problem. There is an overflow, cause the div is long, and div's height saved at bottom. How to do this thing without any problems?

Comment: Post your code, along with an attempt of your own.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class='wrapper'>
   <div class='firstDiv'></div>
   <div class='secondDiv'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}

.firstDiv, .secondDiv{
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible without absolute positioning? Or if with absolute positioning, can parent have width of biggest element, but without js being involved, only using css?

Comment: I mean, absolute positioning doesn't require JS, but yes you could do this without absolute positioning. You could do

.wrapper { white-space: nowrap }
.firstDiv, .secondDiv { width: 100%; display: inline-block; }
.secondDiv { transform: translateX(-100%) }

Comment: The problem with this solution is that wrapper still takes width of both divs combined, while I need it to be only of the longest word http://jsfiddle.net/v40sam7g/, some context - I need to animate transform between those two, and only when I implemented it one way I discovered this problem. So instead of rewriting it I just left it as is, but width is jumping instead of transforming.

Comment: I was assuming fixed widths, but if you need yet another solution, you can replace the transform with `margin-left: -100%` and add `width: 0px` to .secondDiv. http://jsfiddle.net/2bjfgsrL/1/ Note the commend between firstDiv and secondDiv in the HTML, without this the browser will add a space between them, and the position will be off.

Comment: Thanks for another solution, but unfortunately that's still not the solution for me, because I don't know which div is bigger - first or second and it only works if first is bigger - http://jsfiddle.net/5n14au2e/. I have another solution in mind already, not related to css, so this is purely theoretical question at this moment, so only waste time on this if it's interesting for you. Thanks again for feedback.

Answer (score 5):

HTML

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Css :-

```
.one
{
   width: 170px;
height: 170px;
position: relative;
background: red;
}
.two
{
   width: 70px;
height: 70px;
position: absolute;
background: black;
}
```

jsfiddle demo

http://jsfiddle.net/xnqsF/

Comment: This is far more useful as it's very easy to embed the whole apparatus into a containing div that automatically adjusts to fit its contents.

Answer (score 1):

Real answer available via css-grid,

setting the parent to display:grid

and the children to grid-row/column-start:1 as shown in the answer below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50086485/3810321