# Placing two divs on top of each other without using Position:absolute

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to add two divs on top of each other without using Position:absolute, and it is not working.

Does anyone know how to do that??
Thank you.

```
<div class="row" style="background-color:aqua;">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" >   

        <div style="left:0px;">
               <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Label" />
        </div>

        <div style="left:0px;">
             <asp:Button ID="btnJoin" runat="server" Text="a button" 
                  CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary"/>
        </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with position:absolute?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overlay Divs Without Absolute Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027751/overlay-divs-without-absolute-position)

Comment: @Mark i have a navbar located right under this row and for some reason when i add position:absolute to the divs in this row, the whole row gets located behind the navbar.

Comment: add position absolute to only one not both

Comment: @TemaniAfif but this way the divs will not be located on top of one another.

Comment: you make one position abosulte AND you adjust its position to make it in the top of the other one

Answer (score 27):

you can do this using grid.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.parent div {
 padding: 50px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-column-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
  1
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
  2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For me, clearly the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is the exact answer.

Answer (score 2):

If both elements are in normal flow, you could use a negative margin-top on the element which you want to layer on top of it's predecessor:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  padding: 20px;
  background: coral;
}

.box--overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: -40px; /*Change this to a value of your choosing*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">I am box 1</div>
<div class="box box--overlay">I am box 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving position relative to both the elements and align the second element on top of the first by using z-index 2 to the second element and top:(); left:(); that would not effect your navbar.

Comment: this didn't work unfortunately. but thank you anyway :)

Comment: Oh! I am sorry , there are many ways to display a div above another, I believe the easiest way is to nest the second div inside the first one and the just position it absolute giving the first div position relative or setting the z-index of the first element to 0 and the second element to >1, However as per Mark's code modifying .row means modifying the .row class in bootstrap.css as well thereby affecting the whole page

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it though a cleaner way might be to get the width of the element you're covering using javascript so that you can dynamically cover elements without statically putting in exact pixel value for margin-left, as is the case for css for blue div

```css
.red {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  display: inline-block;
}
.blue {
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">red</div>
<div class="blue">blue</div>
```